# C# - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy not invoking when debugging

Tags: .net, angular, single-page-application

I am trying to upgrade a .net 3.1 Angular (SPA template) app to .net 7.0. I am attempting to move away from the older UseSpa() middleware to the newer way for .net core to interact with Spa frameworks leveraging **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy**. I am trying to update our project by modeling it off what comes out of the box in a new .net 7 Angular Spa template.

The issue I am running into is that the Proxy middleware is not being invoked. I am expecting to see something like:

> Launching the SPA proxy...
> This page will automatically redirect to http://localhost:44414 when the SPA proxy is ready.

as the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy package is supposed to be added middleware to launch the npm command and redirect once the `ng serve` is ready. But I never see that or the npm script launched.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Added the package to the .csproj file:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="7.0.1" />
```

2. Updated the LaunchSettings.json to include the environmental variable:

```
"environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
```

3. Updated the project file to include the three Spa properties:

```
 <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:4200</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```

I have tried numerous things to troubleshoot, including making the Program.cs the EXACT same as the template. (to rule out any other middle ware conflicting)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I know the package is installed correclty as I do see a spa.proxy.json in my bin folder. I also tested messing up the environment variable to verify it's taking effect and it does. changing it to:

```
 "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy_WRONG"
```

Produces the correct error running dotnet run:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[11]
      Hosting startup assembly exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy_WRONG failed to execute. See the inner exception for more details.
       ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy_WRONG, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
      File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy_WRONG, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
         at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.ExecuteHostingStartups()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I am running out of ideas of additional things to try. Has anyone had any experience adding **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy** to a .net7 app, and can think of anything I might have missed?

Thank you.

Comment: It is happening the exact same thing to me. Are you running it in Windows or Mac OS?

Answer (score -1):

When I faced this same issue, Opened Visual Studio "Run as administrator" and all worked perfectly!